# Sql server date constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
alter table dbo.transactions
add constraint tk_paiement check ([Date_paiementdu]=[dateTransaction] +(30))
```

i want `date_paiementdu` to be set 30 day after  the datetransaction but its not working

need some help! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a CHECK constraint, but what you appear to want is a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
alter table dbo.transactions 
add tk_Date_paiementdu as (DateAdd(day, 30, [dateTransaction])
```

Comment: yea..  and the 2 date are ( date type)  and when im doing the query  

 this error pop 

"Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) rather than a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
ADD Date_paiementdu AS DATEADD(DAY, 30, dateTransaction);
```

If you want the column to be not nullable or indexed then you will need to use `PERSISTED` and also DateTransaction will need to be not nullable:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
ADD Date_paiementdu AS DATEADD(DAY, 30, dateTransaction) PERSISTED NOT NULL;
```

To clarify further using PERSISTED will actually store the data that is to be displayed in the column, omitting it will keep the column as a virtual column that is calculated each time it is needed.

Comment: @MitchWheat the first one with persisted was actually a mistake, I added persisted to the answer, and accidentally commited the update before adding the reasons why you would want to use persisted.

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of database normalization is to not store calculated values.  With that in mind, you can probably achieve your goal with something like this:

```
where datediff(day, dateTransaction, Date_paiementdu) <= 30
```

The details of how to accomplish this are RDBMS specific, and you didn't specify yours.